# Set color on IONIC 2 component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

I have a simple sidemenu ionic 2 project and I am trying to change the color of the top menu.

```
 <ion-toolbar color="light" >
  <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Light is the default theme color how do I get it to reflect on the ionic application?

I have changed the value in the variables.scss to orange. The nav at the top is still white how do I get it to change to orange?

Comment: Is it the `primary` color?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the color in the `ion-toolbar` tag.

```
<ion-toolbar color="custom"></ion-toolbar>
```

And in the variable.scss file include the `custom` color.

```
$colors:(custom:#your_color_code);
```

Comment: Why doesn't it use the color light that I selected

Comment: I set it to light why do I need to set a custom color when the color I want is there

Comment: So how did you place your menu template then? Can you post your menu template code here ? It will be inside <ion-menu> tag.

Comment: I dont understand what the menu has to do with it as its the top toolbar.

<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="light" >
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>

Comment: I had the same issue, that's why i asked for the menu template code. My code is the same with `ion-menu` inside `ion-header`. I don't know why the color doesn't change for you. Can you post the content in your `variable.scss` file where you specified the color orange. Thank you

Comment: $colors: (
  primary:    #f5b58b,
  secondary:  #ffbb00,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #ff6804,
  dark:       rgb(255, 203, 183)
);

They are just slight changed to the colors I want

Comment: I ended up using [color]="dark" and this worked perfectly

Comment: great, still wondering why the previous idea didn't worked out for you